# Returning Elements From ArrayList Alphabetically

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, arraylist, while-loop

I'm working on a program to manipulate chemical formulae, and I'm writing a method which needs to loop through an ArrayList called "terms" and return the first one alphabetically.

e.g. terms = {Term('H',4),Term('C',2),Term('H',4),Term('C',1)} would return Term('C',2)

I've written this code so far but it's not working. I'm a real beginner to the Java language.

```
public Term nextElement()
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < terms.size()-1; i++)
    {
        int j = 1;
        while (i + j <= terms.size())
        if (terms.get(i).getElement() > terms.get(i+j).getElement())
        {
            terms.remove(i+j++);
            return terms.get(i);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I'd appreciate any ideas or suggestions to solve this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- you can implement `Comparable`  and override `compareTo()`

```
int compareTo(Object obj){
Term term = (Term)obj;
if(term.getElement < this.getElement())
  return 1;
else if (term.getElement == this.getElement())
  return 0;
else
  return -1;
}
```

then use

```
Collection.sort(terms);
```

2-

```
 public Term nextElement()
    {
        char minElement = 'Z';
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < terms.size(); i++)
        {
            if (terms.get(i).getElement() < minElement)
            {
                minElement = terms.get(i).getElement();
                index = i;
            }
        }
        Term temp = terms.get(index);
        terms.remove(index)
        return temp;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! The 2nd method is really clear to me and I used that, but I don't understand why you've put terms.remove(index) just after you've added terms.get(index)? I just got rid of that line and it passes all the tests I wrote

Comment: @JohnSmith if this answer fixed your issue mark it as accepted to help other people who have the same issue

Answer (score 3):

You have two options here:

1. Let your `Term` class implement `Comparable` interface and override its `compareTo()` method. Then you can use `Collections.sort(listOfTerms)` to sort them and loop through.
2. Add class `TermComparator` which implements `Comparator` interface, use `Collections.sort(listOfTerms, new TermComparator())` and loops through the sorted list.

Answer (score 0):

use `Collections.sort(terms);`it will arrange the list alphabetically.

Comment: Won't work without implementing `Comparable` interface by `Term` class

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do:

```
List<Term> terms = //your list
Collections.sort(terms, new Comparator<Term>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Term t1, Term t2) {
        return t1.getElement().compareTo(t2.getElement());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**CODE:**

```
public class CodeSample {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Term> terms=new ArrayList<Term>();
    terms.add(new Term('H',4));
    terms.add(new Term('C',2));
    terms.add(new Term('H',4));
    terms.add(new Term('C',1));
    System.out.println("Before Sorting");
    for(Term term:terms){
        System.out.print(term.toString().concat(" "));
    }
    Collections.sort(terms,new Comparator<Term>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Term object1, Term object2) {                
            if (object1.getElement() != object2.getElement()) {
                return object1.getElement() - object2.getElement();
            } else {
                return object2.getCount() - object1.getCount();
            }           
        }
    });
    //Sorted terms
    System.out.println("After Sorting");
    for(Term term:terms){
        System.out.print(term.toString().concat(" "));
    }
}

public static class Term{
    private char element;
    private int count;
    public Term(char element, int count) {
        super();
        this.element = element;
        this.count = count;
    }
    public char getElement() {
        return element;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Term [element=" + element + ", count=" + count + "]";
    }       
}
 }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Before Sorting
Term [element=H, count=4] Term [element=C, count=2] Term [element=H, count=4] Term [element=C, count=1] 
After Sorting
Term [element=C, count=2] Term [element=C, count=1] Term [element=H, count=4] Term [element=H, count=4]
```

Comment: You compare elements only and forgot about element counts. According to the author Term('C',2) should be followed by Term('C',1).

Comment: @Yaroslav I don't see Term('C',2) should followed by Term('C',1)  implied in the OPs question. I assumed the ordering is enforced on the element names (i.e. first parameter)

Comment: The author wtote: "e.g. terms = {Term('H',4),Term('C',2),Term('H',4),Term('C',1)} would return Term('C',2)" which means counts matters and Term('C',2) should be followed by Term('C',1)

Comment: @Yaroslav   Thank you for input. I have edited the code.